# JNLP XX:-UseSplitVerifier in 1.7

Tags: java-7, jnlp, jvm-arguments

Is there a way how to set -XX:-UseSplitVerifier jvm arg in JNLP file in 1.7? In doc I did not find it is supported and when I tried it is ignored.